# Find the length of the polar curve

Tags: calculus, integration, polar-coordinates, arc-length

How do I find the exact length of the polar curve $$r = 1+sin(\theta)$$
from 
$$\frac{\pi}{3} \leq \theta \leq \pi $$?

I had originally setup my equation as 
$$\int_{\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\pi} \sqrt{(1+\sin(\theta) )^2 + (\cos\theta)^2} * d\theta$$
but that got me the incorrect answer. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure of the definition of the length of a  polar curve?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Yes

Comment: Your expression looks right, but the parentheses are hard to read. We want to integrate the square root of $(1+\sin\theta)^2+\cos^2\theta$, so we want to integrate $\sqrt{2+2\sin\theta}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas sorry. I fixed the parenthesis. Could you explain that a bit more?

Comment: @imranfat that is the derivative of r (necessary for the equation being used)

Comment: I was thinking of area. Never mind...:)

Comment: @Greencat:  How to get from yours to mine? Expand and use $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas oh ok. Do you know how to get to the answer?

Comment: I think so, double angle identity.

Comment: @AndréNicolas could you post your work through as an answer?

Comment: @Greencat: Turned out I had a bit of time, so was able to write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comments, we want 
$$\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi}\sqrt{2+2\sin\theta}\,d\theta.$$
Let $\theta=\frac{\pi}{2}-t$. Then $\sin\theta=\cos t$, and after the substitution we want 
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/6}\sqrt{2+2\cos t}\,dt.$$
But by the identity $\cos(2y)=2\cos^2y-1$, we have $2+2\cos t=4\cos^2(t/2)$. So we want
$$\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/6}2\cos(t/2)\,dt.$$
This integral is straightforward. Note that the $\sin(\pi/12)$ we get as a component of the answer can be expressed *exactly* in terms of square roots, so the final answer has a nice simple form.